# slight issues while implementing a sequence diagram

Tags: php, html, database, web, sequence-diagram

I have a sequence diagram in screenshot below but I have 2 little questions:

Question 1: The pages follow sequence until user gets on `Penalty Marks Information` page, there they decide if they want to `enable penalty marks` of `disable penalty marks`. If enabled then they go to the `Penalty Marks for Each Answer` page, but if they want to disable then they just go straight to the `Assessment Completed` page. My question is that is the diagram below correct when trying to match this or does it need to be implemented in a different way in the diagram.

Question 2: After each page is subbmitted it does it's own insert into a database table, how can also include in diagram that it does an insert into db as well? Can somebody please show an example on how to do this between just two pages so I can see how it is done?

Screenshot of sequence diagram:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: @JasonMcCreary This is part of my individual thesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence diagram does not seem to follow the general approach. From the [WikiPedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) (and the UML  User Guide): a sequence diagram

> depicts the objects and classes involved in the scenario and the
>   sequence of messages exchanged between the objects needed to carry out
>   the functionality of the scenario

So the "swimlanes" should not be labelled with activities like "create an assessment", but with objects in the solution. Which objects you show depends on the system design; in an MVC application, you'd show "assessment controller" talking to an "assessment" model object, which might talk to a database to store and retrieve assessments.

The messages are sent between actors/objects in the system. So, the logged-in teacher sends a message "create" to the assessment controller; the assessment controller validates the message and creates a new "assessment" model object, which in turn might send a "persist" message to the database.

There are, of course, other ways of using sequence diagrams - it depends on the level of granularity you are using. You could simply model the domain entities (teacher, assessment, question, answer etc.) and explore how they send messages to each other to achieve the scenario, or you could model software components (browser, web server, script engine, database) - it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

A very simple version might be like this (I stopped after creating the answers, because I couldn't quite follow the requirement). 
[image: rough sketch]

Apropos question 2: first you have to decide which component tells the database to save the assessment - this depends entirely on your software design. Once you've taken that decision, you draw a line from that component to the database, with a "save" message; the database responds with "success" or "fail".

Comment: Hi, so is my sequence diagram showing how a student navigates through all the pages to create an assessment is incorrect? I am using simply php/html so do I need to change it from `Create an Assessment` to `assessment.php` for example?

Comment: Also for question 2 can I inbetween each swimlane page, include a swimlane saying `Insert` for example and include a solid arrow pointing from previous swimlane to the `Insert` swimlane and then a dash arrow back to previous swimlane if user has more assessments to complete `this is if user has multiple assessments to complete`, and show a solid arrow from `Insert` to next swimlane?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sketch of how it might be done in your case.

Comment: Haha, that was a very quick scketch :) Thanks